# sending href with parameter in a loop

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form action="new_question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>">
<input type="submit" value="New Question">
</form>
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question_table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<a href=\"http://localhost/project/question.php\">" . $row['question'] . $row['q_id'] . "</a>";
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 5 question in my database each with a id. this page prints them as a link in loop. upon clicking any of the link it goes to "question.php" file. there i want to echo the question from the database that was clicked previously. the problem is in "question.php" file how do i find out which link was clicked among thus 5. should i send a parameter along with the link? how the parameter will change in each loop? how do i do it in this page? if i do send a parameter with the link how do i receive it in the "question.php" file?

Comment: `question.php?id=123` and access the variable `$_GET['id']` on `question.php`. [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: but its in a loop. i have change id in each iteration. but how?

Comment: like "$row['q_id']" which will change for each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the id as a parameter on the anchor. We can also remove the id from the anchor text since it's not needed there anymore.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<a href="http://localhost/project/question.php?id=' . $row['q_id'] . '">' . $row['question'] . '</a><br>';
}
```

And then in `question.php` do `$_GET['id']`

Comment: +1 , but I would even suggest to get `$row['q_id']` out of the visible text of the link.

Comment: @Daniel Good suggestion, i updated my answer to suggest this.

Comment: thanks @Kyle Needham. it works! this problem had a simple solution but for some reason i thought it would be much complicated!

Comment: i added "q_id" on anchor text just to show whats going on here! i wouldn't have included it in the final page... thanks for the suggestion anyway @KyleNeedham